# How to ignore route param in location

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am navigating to next page as:

```
$location.path("XXX/YYYY/");
```

current view has URL parameter as:

```
http://www.go.com/?a=true;
```

now when I navigate, it has `XXX/YYYY/"?a=true;`

I have tried :

```
delete $routeParams.a;
```

and

```
delete $location.$$search.a;
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't remove the parameter.

How to set routeparam when navigating to a different page?

Comment: I tried 

delete $routeParams.a;
delete $location.$$search.a;

Comment: which router do you use? ngRoute or ui-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following change fixed my issue :

```
 delete $location.$$search.a;
 $location.replace().path("XXX/YYYY/");

 config: {           
            reloadOnSearch: false
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the path like:

```
http://www.go.com/
```

you can try:

```
$location.url($location.path());
```

Comment: At the same time I need to remove the querystring from the parent of the current page also , reason is when I do history.back it will again get that parameter for routeparam

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution but you can try:

```
if ($location.$$search.a) {
    delete $location.$$search.a;
    $location.$$compose();
}
```